# udev makes duplicate /dev/disk/by-id symlinks for nvme drives & partitions

Tags: udev, nvme

Recently, I noticed that there were extra symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-id` for my NVME drives, with the duplicates having the same name with `_1` appended.

```
# ls -lF /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW{,_1}
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1 -> ../../nvme0n1
```

(serial numbers edited to mostly XXXXXXXX for no particular reason)

and it duplicates the entries for all the partitions on the NVME drives too:

```
$ ls -lF /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1*-part*'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1-part4 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1-part5 -> ../../nvme0n1p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1-part6 -> ../../nvme0n1p6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 29 19:22 /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466XXXXXXXXXXW_1-part7 -> ../../nvme0n1p7
```

This is only happening for my NVME drives, not for my SATA or USB flash drives.

I can't see anything obvious in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules` that would do this.

Anyone know why `udev` is doing this?   And, more importantly, how to stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these lines in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="nvme*[0-9]n*[0-9]", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ATTRS{nsid}=="?*", ENV{ID_NSID}="$attr{nsid}"
# obsolete symlink that might get overridden on adding a new nvme controller, kept for backward compatibility
KERNEL=="nvme*[0-9]n*[0-9]", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="?*", \
  OPTIONS="string_escape=replace", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$env{ID_MODEL}_$env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/nvme-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="nvme*[0-9]n*[0-9]", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="?*", ENV{ID_NSID}=="?*",\
  OPTIONS="string_escape=replace", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$env{ID_MODEL}_$env{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}_$env{ID_NSID}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/nvme-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
```

The first rule sets ID_NSID (namespace id?) of the NVMe device, compare `head /sys/block/nvme*/nsid`. The second rule sets ID_SERIAL and creates the regular `disk/by-id/nvme-ID_SERIAL` symlink. The third rule appends ID_NSID to ID_SERIAL and makes the "duplicate" `disk/by-id/nvme-ID_SERIAL_NSID` symlink.

In `udevadm info /dev/nvme` you'll only see the NSID variant for ID_SERIAL, since the third rule overwrites whatever the second rule had set.

It looks a bit confusing but it seems to be working as intended. If you want to get rid of it, you'd have to disable the third udev rule quoted above.

---

In this [commit c5ba7a2a @ github/systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/c5ba7a2a4dd19a2d31b8a9d52d3c4bdde78387f0) you can also see the same rules repeated for the individual partition symlinks, so you'd have to disable it in both places.

However the intention here seems to be to prefer the _1 links over the regular ones, as those are… uh… namespace-safe? ;-)

I'm not sure about this approach, with a slightly different rule you could protect the regular symlink… this patch just adds new ones without solving the original problem, that's a bit weird. But I don't use namespaces much, so…

Comment: OK, that seems to be where it's happening (i saw those three lines but somehow missed the append of ID_NSID).  Now what I need to find out is why they think adding ID_NSID is somehow safer than just the model and serial number - I would have thought that they were unique, it's not like there's ever going to be another nvme drive in a system with the same model and serial number.

Comment: as for "this patch just adds new ones without solving the original problem, that's a bit weird" - systemd devs seem to have learnt a little from being yelled at for repeatedly breaking people's systems with bizarre changes, now they've figured out that they can get away with it by adding their allegedly "new and improved" thing long before suddenly deleting the old thing that everyone relies on. Then they can say "you had X months/years warning (hidden away in an obscure commit)".

Comment: OK, fixed it in a local override copy in /etc/udev/rules.d/.  I also got rid of the wwn-.* and nvme-eui.* symlinks too - I never use them and they're just an annoyance whenever I create or export & re-import a zfs pool (the devices in each vdev can get those ugly/useless names rather than the model_serial name I rely on if I ever have to replace a disk)